# Remove borders in hyperlink with revtex

Tags: hyperref, natbib, revtex, hyperlink, doi

I need to use the `revtex4-1` class for my article, and it seems the `hyperref` package is not working properly with this class. Most of my citations contain a `doi` field, but no `url` field. I want to make a hyperlink for the citations, and the `hyperref` package should be able to do that. However, it seems the options are not passed properly, as I'm trying to get rid of the boxes around the links. Note that `revtex4-1` uses `natbib`, and thus cannot use BibTeX.

So how can I get rid of the box surrounding the link, in this MWE?

```
\documentclass[aps,showpacs,twocolumn,prl,amsmath,amssymb,superscriptaddress,intlimits]{revtex4-1}                                                       
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}

@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    doi =          "10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Natbib is loaded with revtex

\begin{document}

Let us cite \cite{einstein}.

\lipsum[1]

\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

[image: Outpub]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This URL-style link is inserted by [`natbib`](//ctan.org/pkg/natbib) which is loaded by [`revtex4-1`](//ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1). You can get away from that by using the following hack:

```
\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{%
  \renewcommand{\doi}[1]{doi: ##1}% Override \doi
  \let\bibitem\oldbibitem% Restore \bibitem
  \oldbibitem% Call old \bibitem
}
```

This updates (the first use of) `\bibitem` to override how `\doi{<doi>}` prints its argument. Instead of printing it like a URL, it just prints the DOI with a `doi:`  prefix. After the first use of `\bibitem`, the original definition of `\bibitem` is fully restored.

[image]

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\let\oldbibitem\bibitem
\renewcommand{\bibitem}{%
  \renewcommand{\doi}[1]{doi: ##1}% Override \doi
  \let\bibitem\oldbibitem% Restore \bibitem
  \oldbibitem% Call old \bibitem
}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{main.bib}
@article{
  einstein,
  author = "Albert Einstein",
  title =  "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
      [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal = "Annalen der Physik",
  volume = "322",
  number = "10",
  pages = "891--921",
  year = "1905",
  doi = "10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}  % Natbib is loaded with revtex

\begin{document}

Let us cite \cite{einstein}.

\lipsum[1]

\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner! I just had to make a small edit to make a clickable link, where I use
`\renewcommand{\doi}[1]{doi: \href{http://dx.doi.org/##1}{##1}}`